# Phpstorm - изменить язык документации функций

Tags: php, phpstorm

В phpstorm есть комбинация клавиш ctrl+Q - показ быстрой документации функции. Если поставить курсор на функцию и нажать комбинацию клавиш вылазит модальное окошко с описанием функции и ссылка на php.net

Документация в окошке на английском, ссылка также ведет на англ. версию сайта php.net.

Нельзя ли как-то изменить на русский вариант быстрой документации или хотя бы изменить ссылки так, чтобы те вели на русс.версию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ссылки и текст документации не подтягиваются из сети. Они хранятся в самом phpStorm'е как обычный phpDoc, поэтому просто настроить это нельзя.

Пример `/PhpStorm-145.970.40/plugins/php/lib/php.jar!/stubs/standard/standard_1.php`
GitHub: https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs

Можно форкнуть/склонировать репозиторий, внести желаемые изменения и указать phpStorm'у путь к новым файлам в `Languages & Frameworks / PHP / Advanced settings`

*Проще поставить какое-нибудь расширение в браузер для редиректа на ru версию php.net*

Comment: phpstorm 2016 - нет папки  stubs. И в настройках нет Advanced settings))

Comment: v145.970.40 - это как раз 2016.1.1

Comment: ``Advanced settings`` легко пропустить - она внизу свёрнута. А чтобы открыть файл - перейдите к объявлению встроенной функции. Сам он упакован в ``php.jar``.